# How to properly debug with Capybara/Poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I am playing around with capybara/poltergeist perfect duo, but I am having trouble to properly debugging. 
I was testing a simple script:

```
logger = Logger.new "./log/who-scored-com.log"
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false,
                                         debug: true,
                                         logger: logger)
end
browser = Capybara.current_session
browser.visit 'https://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores'
browser.save_page 'page.html'
```

I am expecting that the script grap the page normally and saves it, but the page is empty and this is returned:

```
`Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:351:in `command'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:34:in `visit'`
```

Now, this don't give me nothing about this error. I catch the exception and print it and it gives me:

`"Request to 'https://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status"`

Even if I have no idea why the address do not respond for capybara (and any hint would be appreciate :) ) I don't understand why the `:debug` options used in configuration doesn't seem to give me no info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of issues

1. the poltergeist logger option is defined as '(Object responding to puts) - The ruby 2.3.0 standard library Logger object doesnt respond to puts so it's not valid.
2. You're example doesn't have `Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist` so I'm not sure if it is actually using the driver you're configuring there or a previously defined one (I would have expected an error on the Logger object if it was)
3. `debug: true` will add debugging for poltergeist to the log, but there is also debugging info from phantomjs. That is generated by passing `phantomjs_options: ['--debug=true'], phantomjs_logger: <an IO object - again not a Logger object>` to the driver
4. The error you're actually hitting is the connection being refused due to not being able to negotiate an ssl protocol - to fix it add the required ssl protocol as a phantomjs option -  `phantomjs_options: ['--ssl-protocol=TLSv1.2']

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to work, but I would love to know how you knew that 'TLSv1.2' was the right param for the `--ssl-protocol`

Comment: @ciaoben Because of the recent ssl security issues many sites have increased the minimum protocol they will accept for an encrypted connection.  If you run `phantomjs --help` you'll see the latest protocol available is 'TLSv1.2'  - please accept the answer if it helped you so others know the issue is solved

Comment: Interestingly, the SSL protocol recommendation above resolved this for me.  Note, I did change it to TLS 1.3 since it is 2020.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like the following in a standalone ruby script, adjust `driver_options` to suit your taste.

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

class NilLogger
  def puts * ; end
end

def setup_session
  driver_options = { js_errors: false,
                     logger: NilLogger.new,
                     phantomjs_logger: STDOUT,
                     phantomjs_options: ['--debug=true'],
                     debug: false  }
  Capybara.configure do |conf|
    conf.run_server = false
    conf.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app, driver_options
    end
    conf.current_driver = :poltergeist
  end
  Capybara.current_session
end

browser = setup_session()
browser.visit 'https://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores'
browser.save_page 'page.html'
```

Comment: What does `*` in the NilLogger.puts does?

Comment: It allows the method to accept any number of arguments, it is the same as `def puts(*a) ; end`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
 Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :inspector => true)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
```

as shown [here](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#remote-debugging-experimental)?

Comment: It is not the kind of test that I need... anyway, I am launching the script on a vagrant VM, so it would be useless since I have no screen, only the terminal